# How to store relatively static but configurable information

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, application-settings, property-list

I have a table (dictionary of dictionaries) to store mapping of integers to strings. I have types and sub-types. e.g. type 1=>fruits and sub-type 1=>apple.

The mapping shall be configurable in my setting interface, but for the reset of the application, it's rather static. So I don't want to read from property-list every time I check the mapping. I'd like to only read once when program starts and only write when user changes setting.

Where should I keep this table at runtime? I have two approaches in mind: 
(1) is to put the entire table as a variable in the application delegate, in this case, I need to use objectForKey twice every time I need to get a string.
(2) is to create a class with a static variable (not sure how to do it yet) and use class method to get the mapping e.g. +(NSString) stringForType: subType:

Could you please evaluate these two approaches or suggest better solutions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to read the plist every time? If the dictionary is large enough that reading it from disk every time is too slow, then it's probably too large to keep in memory.

Comment: Wouldn't it be slow if I read from plist everytime? considering if I put it in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Reading and writing plists is surprisingly fast. Why not give it a go and profile it? You could always do it in a background thread and show an activity indicator while it loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't really matter where you put it, as long as you keep exactly one copy of it, the important thing that you should check out is [valueForKeyPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/valueForKeyPath%3a).  If you store in a plist, and save to the plist regularly you have the great benefit of persistence. You can get that automatically with the `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];` object.